# ROPC flow tries doing userrealm discovery and fails

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to use MSAL to get an access token using B2Cs ROPC flow. However, it fails trying to use regular AAD (not B2Cs) user realm discovery, which obviously fails since user id does not have a domain.

Fiddler shows that one of the calls MSAL executes is: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/userrealm/user1?api-version=1.0 . Note 'user1', which is a valid user id in B2C but not in AAD.

```
            Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/mrochonb2cprod.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_ROP/.well-known/openid-configuration";
            var pwd = new SecureString();
            foreach (var c in "...") pwd.AppendChar(c);
            var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(ClientId)
                    .WithB2CAuthority(Authority)
                        .Build();
            var ar = await app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePasswordAsync(Scopes, "user1", pwd);
```

Comment: Have you tried https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{tenant}/{policyName} for authority? https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AAD-B2C-specifics

Comment: @TonyJu is correct, you do not need to include `.well-known/openid-configuration` in the authority.

Comment: I have tried: var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{_tenantShortName}.onmicrosoft.com/{_ropPolicy}/"; Results in 'unsupported user type 'uknown''. var authority = $"https://{_tenantShortName}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{_tenantShortName}.onmicrosoft.com/{_ropPolicy}/"; starts user realm discovery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have confirmed this with the Microsoft engineer. Currently they haven't tested `MSAL aquiretokenusernamepassword()` method with B2C user and there is no sample for this. This feature is in public preview. They have tested this flow extensively, in production, with AppAuth for iOS and AppAuth for Android. You can find more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc).
[image]

But the ropc flow works fine, you can use the post request instead.

```
POST /yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=B2C_1_ROPC_Auth HTTP/1.1
Host: yourtenant.b2clogin.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

username=leadiocl%40trashmail.ws&password=Passxword1&grant_type=password&scope=openid+bef22d56-552f-4a5b-b90a-1988a7d634ce+offline_access&client_id=bef22d56-552f-4a5b-b90a-1988a7d634ce&response_type=token+id_token


{ 
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik9YQjNhdTNScWhUQWN6R0RWZDM5djNpTmlyTWhqN2wxMjIySnh6TmgwRlkifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3RlLmNwaW0ud2luZG93cy5uZXQvZjA2YzJmZTgtNzA5Zi00MDMwLTg1ZGMtMzhhNGJmZDllODJkL3YyLjAvIiwiZXhwIjoxNTEzMTMwMDc4LCJuYmYiOjE1MTMxMjY0NzgsImF1ZCI6ImJlZjIyZDU2LTU1MmYtNGE1Yi1iOTBhLTE5ODhhN2Q2MzRjZSIsIm9pZCI6IjNjM2I5NjljLThjNDktNGUxMS1hNGVmLWZkYjJmMzkyZjA0OSIsInN1YiI6Ik5vdCBzdXBwb3J0ZWQgY3VycmVudGx5LiBVc2Ugb2lkIGNsYWltLiIsImF6cCI6ImJlZjIyZDU2LTU1MmYtNGE1Yi1iOTBhLTE5ODhhN2Q2MzRjZSIsInZlciI6IjEuMCIsImlhdCI6MTUxMzEyNjQ3OH0.MSEThYZxCS4SevBw3-3ecnVLUkucFkehH-gH-P7SFcJ-MhsBeQEpMF1Rzu_R9kUqV3qEWKAPYCNdZ3_P4Dd3a63iG6m9TnO1Vt5SKTETuhVx3Xl5LYeA1i3Slt9Y7LIicn59hGKRZ8ddrQzkqj69j723ooy01amrXvF6zNOudh0acseszt7fbzzofyagKPerxaeTH0NgyOinLwXu0eNj_6RtF9gBfgwVidRy9OzXUJnqm1GdrS61XUqiIUtv4H04jYxDem7ek6E4jsH809uSXT0iD5_4C5bDHrpO1N6pXSasmVR9GM1XgfXA_IRLFU4Nd26CzGl1NjbhLnvli2qY4A", 
    "token_type": "Bearer", 
    "expires_in": "3600", 
    "refresh_token": "eyJraWQiOiJacW9pQlp2TW5pYVc2MUY0TnlfR3REVk1EVFBLbUJLb0FUcWQ1ZWFja1hBIiwidmVyIjoiMS4wIiwiemlwIjoiRGVmbGF0ZSIsInNlciI6IjEuMCJ9.aJ_2UW14dh4saWTQ0jLJ7ByQs5JzIeW_AU9Q_RVFgrrnYiPhikEc68ilvWWo8B20KTRB_s7oy_Eoh5LACsqU6Oz0Mjnh0-DxgrMblUOTAQ9dbfAT5WoLZiCBJIz4YT5OUA_RAGjhBUkqGwdWEumDExQnXIjRSeaUBmWCQHPPguV1_5wSj8aW2zIzYIMbofvpjwIATlbIZwJ7ufnLypRuq_MDbZhJkegDw10KI4MHJlJ40Ip8mCOe0XeJIDpfefiJ6WQpUq4zl06NO7j8kvDoVq9WALJIao7LYk_x9UIT-3d0W0eDBHGSRcNgtMYpymaN9ltx6djcEesXNn4CFnWG3g.y6KKeA9EcsW9zW-g.TrTSgn4WBt18gezegxihBla9SLSTC3YfDROQsL9K4yX4400FKlTlf-2l9CnpGTEdWXVi7sIMHCl8S4oUiXd-rvY2mn_NfDrbbVJfgKp1j7Nnq9FFyeJEFcP_FtUXgsNTG9iwfzWox04B1d845qNRWiS9N8BhAAAIdz5N0ChHuOxsVOC0Y_Ly3DNe-JQyXcq964M6-jp3cgi4UqMxT837L6pLY5Ih_iPsSfyHzstsFeqyUIktnzt1MpTlyW-_GDyFK1S-SyV8PPQ7phgFouw2jho1iboHX70RlDGYyVmP1CfQzKE_zWxj3rgaCZvYMWN8fUenoiatzhvWkUM7dhqKGjofPeL8rOMkhl6afLLjObzhUg3PZFcMR6guLjQdEwQFufWxGjfpvaHycZSKeWu6-7dF8Hy_nyMLLdBpUkdrXPob_5gRiaH72KvncSIFvJLqhY3NgXO05Fy87PORjggXwYkhWh4FgQZBIYD6h0CSk2nfFjR9uD9EKiBBWSBZj814S_Jdw6HESFtn91thpvU3hi3qNOi1m41gg1vt5Kh35A5AyDY1J7a9i_lN4B7e_pknXlVX6Z-Z2BYZvwAU7KLKsy5a99p9FX0lg6QweDzhukXrB4wgfKvVRTo.mjk92wMk-zUSrzuuuXPVeg", 
    "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik9YQjNhdTNScWhUQWN6R0RWZDM5djNpTmlyTWhqN2wxMjIySnh6TmgwRlkifQ.eyJleHAiOjE1MTMxMzAwNzgsIm5iZiI6MTUxMzEyNjQ3OCwidmVyIjoiMS4wIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly90ZS5jcGltLndpbmRvd3MubmV0L2YwNmMyZmU4LTcwOWYtNDAzMC04NWRjLTM4YTRiZmQ5ZTgyZC92Mi4wLyIsInN1YiI6Ik5vdCBzdXBwb3J0ZWQgY3VycmVudGx5LiBVc2Ugb2lkIGNsYWltLiIsImF1ZCI6ImJlZjIyZDU2LTU1MmYtNGE1Yi1iOTBhLTE5ODhhN2Q2MzRjZSIsImFjciI6ImIyY18xYV9yZXNvdXJjZW93bmVydjIiLCJpYXQiOjE1MTMxMjY0NzgsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTUxMzEyNjQ3OCwib2lkIjoiM2MzYjk2OWMtOGM0OS00ZTExLWE0ZWYtZmRiMmYzOTJmMDQ5IiwiYXRfaGFzaCI6Ikd6QUNCTVJtcklwYm9OdkFtNHhMWEEifQ.iAJg13cgySsdH3cmoEPGZB_g-4O8KWvGr6W5VzRXtkrlLoKB1pl4hL6f_0xOrxnQwj2sUgW-wjsCVzMc_dkHSwd9QFZ4EYJEJbi1LMGk2lW-PgjsbwHPDU1mz-SR1PeqqJgvOqrzXo0YHXr-e07M4v4Tko-i_OYcrdJzj4Bkv7ZZilsSj62lNig4HkxTIWi5Ec2gD79bPKzgCtIww1KRnwmrlnCOrMFYNj-0T3lTDcXAQog63MOacf7OuRVUC5k_IdseigeMSscrYrNrH28s3r0JoqDhNUTewuw1jx0X6gdqQWZKOLJ7OF_EJMP-BkRTixBGK5eW2YeUUEVQxsFlUg" 
}
```

Comment: Hm, I tried this from Postman and get an error. Here is my POST: POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/mrochonb2cprod.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=B2C_1_ROP HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
...

grant_type=password&username=user1&password=xxx&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fmrochonb2cprod.onmicrosoft.com%2Fwebapi%2Fread_policies&client_id=8fb944a0-4f6a-4510-a02c-eb0cd1a21c6f&client_secret=yyy. Error: AADB2C90224: Resource owner flow has not been enabled (my b2C_1_ROP is based off ROPC template).

Comment: OK, works! The application using ROP has to be registered as Native Client (I was using a WebApp). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[MSAL.NET v3.0.5-preview+](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/releases/tag/3.0.5-preview) works with B2C using the ROPC flow. For more information on using MSAL, see this [section of the MSAL.NET wiki](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AAD-B2C-specifics#resource-owner-password-credentials-ropc-with-b2c).